# Jupyter lab: module not found though package already installed

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

This is the complaint that I got:

```
   ~\Documents\IT\2020 SUM\32933\Resemblyzer\resemblyzer\audio.py in <module>
          4 from typing import Optional, Union
          5 import numpy as np
    ----> 6 import webrtcvad
          7 import librosa
          8 import struct

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webrtcvad'
```

After checking solutions, I tried `sys.executable` and `sys.path`
then here are the outputs:

```
C:\Anaconda\python.exe


['C:\\Users\\Jocelyn Huang\\Documents\\IT\\2020 SUM\\32933\\Resemblyzer', 'C:\\Anaconda\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda', '', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\Jocelyn Huang\\.ipython']
```

Then I check the root package, It has "webrtcvad":
[image: pip list 1]
[image: pip list 2]

I also tried the conda env, though the package is also available, I still received the same complaint in this env:
[image: conda env package]
[image: conda env package 2]

After many attempts, I still cannot figure out what it going on here,
excuse my poor knowledge about this...

Comment: Per the site guidelines, please do not post screenshots as significant parts of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

- Uninstall webrtcvad
  `pip uninstall webrtcvad` `conda uninstall webrtcvad`
- Take restart of your system
- Install webrtcvad again
  `conda install webrtcvad`

Also to check package installed with conda you need to do `conda list` instead of `pip list`

I don't really have the answer as to why this happens, but recently it happened with me and steps shared above resolved it.

Comment: Webrtcvad is not available in conda, so I have to use pip...
though it did not go through, thank you for your help.